# Questão de matrizes

Tags: c, c++, c++14

Bem, a questão pode que para que

> - Escreva um algoritmo que leia uma matriz **A(5,2)** e a escreva.
> - Verifique, a seguir, quais os elementos de *A* estão repetidos e
>   quantas vezes cada um está repetido.
> - Escrever cada elemento
>   repetido com uma mensagem dizendo quantas vezes cada elemento aparece
>   em *A*.

Dai como eu não estava conseguindo ver quais números se repetiam na matriz, transformei essa matriz em um *vetor[10]*, e até consegui contar quais números se repetem, só preciso colocar agora **quantas vezes eles se repetem**. Segue o código.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
    
int main(){    
    int A[5][2];
    int vetor[10];
    int cont;
    int cont2;
    int cont3=0;

    cout << ("Digite numeros para a matriz:") << endl;
    for(cont=0;cont<5;cont++){
        for(cont2=0;cont2<2;cont2++) {
            cin >> A[cont][cont2];
        }
    }    

    for(cont=0;cont<5;cont++) {
        for(cont2=0;cont2<2;cont2++) {
            vetor[cont3]=A[cont][cont2];
            cont3++;
        }
    }

    for (cont = 0; cont < 10; cont++) {
        for (cont2 = cont+1; cont2 < 10; cont2++) {
            if (vetor[cont] == vetor[cont2]) {
                cout << ("Valor repetido:") << vetor[cont]<< endl;
            }  
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Dai como eu não estava conseguindo ver quais números se repetiam na
> matriz, transformei essa matriz em um vetor[10], e até consegui contar
> quais números se repetem, só preciso colocar agora quantas vezes eles
> se repetem.

Talvez não deva considerar como "transformar". C++ não tem vetores como em FORTRAN. Apenas vetores. E vetores de vetores e assim por diante. Como os valores ficam lá enfileirados na memória um depois do outro, linha a linha, sua "matriz" 5x2 é na verdade um vetor de 10 `int` a partir do endereço de início.

Seu programa está muito, mas muito confuso :(

Veja esse trecho

```
   cout << ("Digite numeros para a matriz:") << endl;
    for(cont=0;cont<5;cont++){
        for(cont2=0;cont2<2;cont2++) {
            cin >> A[cont][cont2];
        }
    }
```

Use nomes mais expressivos... `cont` e `cont2` é maldade. E nunca declare essas variáveis de controle do loop fora do loop. É um desastre. Esses valores ficam vivos durante todo o programa e fica impossível de controlar...

E ajude o usuário e você mesmo dizendo o que ele está digitando a cada momento. Deixar a tela preta e ler os valores UM por UM é muito chato e um inferno pra controlar.

A menos que o enunciado diga claramente que a matriz deve ser lida do usuário NUNCA faça isso. É só dor de cabeça. Nunca escreva um programa interativo se não for obrigado.

É muito mais fácil e seguro ler de um arquivo. Você pode repetir os testes facilmente. Pode digitar a matriz direto no IDE. Salvar vários arquivos de teste...

E principalmente nos testes não precisa ficar inventando 10 valores a toda hora com o programa eventualmente fechando na sua cara.

#### De volta ao programa

Você não prece ter escrito um programa em C++ e sim um programa em C. E sequer tem o mínimo que o enunciado pede, que é mostrar a função lida.

Uma vez que tenha feito isso, entenda que há muitas maneiras de fazer isso, mais para o lado C ou mais para o lado C++.

Um jeito comprido e pouco eficiente seria ordenar a matriz em outra e marcar os valores que são repetidos, e depois juntar uma tabela.

Um jeito mais C++ seria usar alguns dos algoritmos de STL e algum container.

Uma solução possível seria fazer algo como o selection sort, que vai separando o menor a cada loop na matriz, e ao invés de inverter com o primeiro e ir ordenando você apenas vê se o elemento está duplicado e quantas vezes aparece na tabela e vai guardando em uma matriz de resultados. Ao final é só mostrar o que tem lá.

Pode não ter nada se a matriz for de elementos todos distintos, pode ter um único elemento e ter uma matriz de 10 elementos constantes....

Claro que em C++ o esperado seria ter uma classe para a qual você passasse o nome do arquivo no disco e o número de linhas e colunas e ela lesse a matriz e calculasse tudo...

#### Um exemplo em C++

Uma classe `kit`, uma `struct` nesse exemplo, serve. Declarada assim em `kit.h`

```
#pragma once
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <new>
using namespace std;

struct kit
{
    string  arquivo; // a origem
    int     C;  // colunas
    int     L;  // linhas
    int     N;  // tamanho, so pra nao mult. toda hora.

    int*    matriz; // a matriz
    struct  Par
    {
        int     posicao;
        int     quantos;

    }*          status; // o mapa de repetidos
    int         n_repetidos; // o total

    int     calcula_repetidos();
    int     le(string arquivo); // le a matriz

    kit(int, int, const char*); // o normal: LxC e arquivo
    kit() : kit(5, 2, "entrada.txt") {};
    ~kit();

    friend ostream& operator<<( ostream& sai, const kit& uma);

private:
    kit::Par     busca_menor();
    kit::Par     busca_menor(int);
};
```

A idéia é simples: ao declarar um `kit` se o cara não especifica nada o programa vai tentar ler uma matriz 2 x 5 do arquivo "entrada.txt" no diretório corrente. É o seu problema original. Mas o problema não depende do tamanho da matriz ou do arquivo onde ela está então o conveniente é poder passar como parâmetros, ou não?

#### um programa que usa essa `struct`

```
int         main(void)
{
    kit teste;
    cout << "(Testando com 5x2)\n" << teste << endl;

    kit uma55(5, 5, "55.txt");
    cout << "(Agora 5x5)\n" << uma55 << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

`teste` foi declarado sem parâmetros então vai usar o tamanho 5x2 e o arquivo "entrada.txt". O `cout` mostra o texto e o operador `<<` foi redefinido para essa struct `kit`de modo que vai escrever o que a gente programar, sempre que ler cout << coisa e `coisa` for um `kit`. Isso é típico de C++ e muito conveniente.

E estou mostrando um exemplo, afinal ;)

A segunda `struct` vai usar uma matriz 5x5 e o outro arquivo. Tem exemplos aqui embaixo. Não precisa digitar nada se quiser testar e alterar. Só copiar e colar daqui :)

#### as funções na struct

São só 2 métodos e na verdade tudo anda sózinho, como viu em `main()`, porque o construtor de `kit`, a função que cria cada ocorrência de `kit` chama `le()` para ler o arquivo e `calcula_repetidos` para, bem, calcular os repetidos.

`status` dentro da `struct` é um vetor de pares onde estão as ocorrências de repetidos na matriz, primeiro a posição e depois o número de repetições. Apenas os valores que tem repetição estarão lá.

#### `calcula_repetidos()`

Esse é o código

```
int         kit::calcula_repetidos()
{
    Par res = busca_menor();
    if (res.quantos > 1)
    {   // guarda esse
        *status = res;
        n_repetidos = 1;
    }
    // tenta encontrar algum outro elemento
    // a matriz pode ser constante
    res = busca_menor(*(matriz+ res.posicao));
    while (res.quantos > 0)
    {   
        if (res.quantos > 1)
        {   // guarda esse
            status[n_repetidos] = res;
            n_repetidos += 1;
        }
        int limite = *(matriz + res.posicao);
        res = busca_menor( *(matriz+ res.posicao) );
    };
    return n_repetidos;
};
```

E a idéia é primeiro identificar o menor de todos em `busca_menor()` e depois enquanto tiver algum valor novo ir testando em `busca_menor(limite)` se ele se repete, usando como limite o menor valor já visto. Como eu disse, é o algoritmo do selection sort(), o mais simples de todos. Veja no código e pergunte se não entender algo

#### o arquivo 5 x 2 do teste

```
1 2
3 4
5 6 
7 8 
9 9
```

#### o arquivo 5 x 5 do teste

```
12 12 2 2 3
3 4 4 5 5 
6 6 7 7 8
8 9 9 21 12 
12 2 3 4 5
```

#### o resultado ao rodar `main()` como acima

```
Lendo matriz 5x2 a partir de entrada.txt
(Testando com 5x2)

Matriz 5x2 lida de "entrada.txt"

         1         2
         3         4
         5         6
         7         8
         9         9

1 elementos repetidos:

9 (2X)

Lendo matriz 5x5 a partir de 55.txt
(Agora 5x5)

Matriz 5x5 lida de "55.txt"

        12        12         2         2         3
         3         4         4         5         5
         6         6         7         7         8
         8         9         9        21        12
        12         2         3         4         5

9 elementos repetidos:

2 (3X)
3 (3X)
4 (3X)
5 (3X)
6 (2X)
7 (2X)
8 (2X)
9 (2X)
12 (4X)
```

Sem grandes pretensões, é só um exemplo e não testei quase nada.

Eis o código, em um único arquivo que pode compilar direto

```
#include "kit.h"
using namespace std;

int         main(void)
{
    kit teste;
    cout << "(Testando com 5x2)\n" << teste << endl;

    kit uma55(5, 5, "55.txt");
    cout << "(Agora 5x5)\n" << uma55 << endl;

    return 0;
}


kit::       kit(int l, int c, const char* nome) :
    C(c), L(l), matriz(nullptr), status(nullptr),
    n_repetidos(0), arquivo(nome), N(l*c)
{
    int res = le(nome);
    if (res < 0)
    {
        cerr << "Erro " << res << " lendo os dados de " << nome << endl;
        return;
    }
    n_repetidos = calcula_repetidos();
};


kit::       ~kit()
{
    delete[] matriz;
    delete[] status;
}


kit::Par    kit::busca_menor()
{
    int menor = 0;
    Par res;
    res.quantos = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < N; i++)
    {
        if (*(matriz + i) < *(matriz + menor))
        {
            menor = i;
            res.quantos = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            if (*(matriz + i) == *(matriz + menor)) res.quantos++;
        }
    };  // for()
    res.posicao = menor;
    return res;
};


kit::Par    kit::busca_menor(int limite)
{
    Par    res;
    res.quantos = 0;
    int achou = 0;
    int menor = 0;
    for (auto i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        if (*(matriz + i) <= limite) continue;
        // ao menos esse maior que  limite
        menor = i;
        achou = 1;
        break;
    };  // for()

    if (achou == 0) return res;
    res.quantos = 1;
    for (auto i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        if (*(matriz + i) <= limite) continue;
        if (i == menor) continue;
        if (*(matriz + i) < *(matriz + menor))
        {
            menor = i;
            res.quantos = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            if (*(matriz + i) == *(matriz + menor)) res.quantos++;
        }
    };  // for()
    res.posicao = menor;
    return res;
};


int         kit::calcula_repetidos()
{
    Par res = busca_menor();
    if (res.quantos > 1)
    {   // guarda esse
        *status = res;
        n_repetidos = 1;
    }
    // tenta encontrar algum outro elemento
    // a matriz pode ser constante
    res = busca_menor(*(matriz+ res.posicao));
    while (res.quantos > 0)
    {   
        if (res.quantos > 1)
        {   // guarda esse
            status[n_repetidos] = res;
            n_repetidos += 1;
        }
        int limite = *(matriz + res.posicao);
        res = busca_menor( *(matriz+ res.posicao) );
    };
    return n_repetidos;
};


int         kit::le(string arquivo)
{
    ifstream entra { arquivo };
    istream_iterator<int> in {entra};
    istream_iterator<int> FIM   {};

    if (!entra.good())
    {
        cerr << "Erro tentando abrir " <<
            arquivo << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    // abriu o arquivo, entao aloca os vetores para ler
    size_t tamanho = sizeof(int) * L * C; // o simples
    // pode estar lendo de novo
    if (matriz != nullptr) delete[] matriz;
    if (status != nullptr) delete[] status;
    matriz = new int[tamanho];
    status = new Par[tamanho];

    cerr << "Lendo matriz " << L << "x" << C << 
        " a partir de " << arquivo << "\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < L; i += 1)
        for (int j = 0; j < C; j += 1)
        {
            if (in == FIM)
            {
                cout << "Fim de arquivo inesperado!\n";
                delete[] matriz;
                delete[] status;
                matriz = nullptr;
                return -1;
            };  // if()
            *(matriz + (i * C) + j) = *in++;
        }
    entra.close();
    return L*C; // retorna o total de itens lidos para a matriz
}


ostream& operator<<(ostream& sai, const kit& uma)
{
    cout << "\nMatriz " << uma.L << "x" << uma.C <<
        " lida de \"" << uma.arquivo << "\"\n\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < uma.L; i += 1)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < uma.C; j += 1)
        {
            cout << setw(10) << *(uma.matriz + (i * uma.C) + j);
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    if (uma.n_repetidos < 1)
    {
        cout << "\nSem elementos repetidos\n";
        return sai;
    }
    cout << "\n" << uma.n_repetidos << " elementos repetidos:\n\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < uma.n_repetidos; i += 1)
    {
        cout <<
            uma.matriz[uma.status[i].posicao] << " (" <<
            uma.status[i].quantos << "X)\n";
    }
    return sai;
}
```

Não vou explicar todo o programa porque é muito chato e não sei se precisa, mas fique a vontade para perguntar qualquer coisa.

Comment: Valeu amigo, vou pegar tuas dicas e melhorar aqui.