# Como mostrar quantos elementos foram repetidos X vezes em uma matriz e quantas vezes foi repetido?

Tags: c, array, matriz, for

"Faça um programa em C que leia um número inteiro A e uma matriz V[4][4] de inteiros. Conte quantos valores iguais a A estão na matriz e mostre o resultado."

Quando eu repito um mesmo número mais de uma vez, o programa mostra que foi repetido uma determinada quantia de vezes errada.

Ficaria grato se alguém pudesse apontar qual foi meu erro.

````
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LIN 4
#define COL 4

int main()
{

    int i, j, k, w, repetiu = 0, repete = 1, MAT[LIN][COL];

    for (i = 0; i < LIN; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < COL; j++)
        {
            printf("Digite o elemento da linha [%d] e coluna [%d]: ", i + 1, j + 1);
            scanf("%d", &MAT[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < LIN; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < COL; j++)
        {
            printf("%d  ", MAT[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    for (i = 0; i < LIN; i++)
    {
        for (j = i + 1; j < COL; j++)
        {
            for (k = 0; k < LIN; k++)
            {
                for (w = k + 1; w < COL; w++)
                {
                    if (MAT[i][j] == MAT[k][w])
                    {
                        repetiu++;
                        repete++;
                        printf("\nO número %d foi repetido %d vezes.", MAT[i][j], repete);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (repetiu == 0)
    {
        printf("\nNenhum número foi repetido.");
    }

    return 0;
}```
````

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma possível correção para o código está [aqui](https://godbolt.org/z/eYc34nG48) e também transcrita abaixo.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define LIN 4
#define COL 4
#define SIZE 10

int main(void)
{
    int MAT[LIN][COL];
    char buffer[SIZE];

    // Pede que o usuário insira o elemento a ser comparado com os elementos da matriz
    int elementoBase;
    printf("Digite o elemento a ser comparado: ");
    fgets(buffer, SIZE, stdin);
    elementoBase = atof(buffer);

    // Pede ao usuário que insira os elementos da matriz
    for (int i = 0; i < LIN; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < COL; j++) {
            printf("Digite o elemento da linha [%d] e coluna [%d]: ", i + 1, j + 1);
            fgets(buffer, SIZE, stdin);
            MAT[i][j] = atof(buffer);
        }
    }

    // Escreve a matriz e conta os elementos repetidos
    int repeticoes = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < LIN; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < COL; j++) {
            printf("%d  ", MAT[i][j]);
            if (MAT[i][j] == elementoBase) {
                ++repeticoes;
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    if (repeticoes == 0) {
        printf("\nNenhum número foi repetido.");
    }
    else {
        printf(" O elemento %d foi repetido %d", elementoBase, repeticoes);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Pontos a observar:

1. **Linha 17.** [`scanf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) não é considerada uma função segura por seu risco de overflow. Ela pode ser substituída por [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets). Problemas relacionados à `scanf` são discutidos [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2430303/disadvantages-of-scanf).
2. As variáveis `int i, j, k, w` podem ser deslocadas para dentro de seus respectivos `for`. Com isso, o código fica mais limpo.
3. **Linha 16**. O elemento `A` foi colocado como um número a escolha do usuário e chamado de `elementoBase`.
4. **Linha 30**. Não é necessário o aninhamento de 4 `for`. A matriz deve ser percorrida uma única vez (linha e coluna, por isso os dois laços `for`) e para cada elemento é verificado se é igual ao elemento `A`. Se for, incrementa a variável `repeticoes`. Nota-se também que a variável `repeticoes` é declarada logo antes de ser usada, ao invés de ser no início do programa. De modo geral, é bom declarar uma variável o mais próximo possível de seu uso. Além disso, a escrita da matriz e a contagem de elementos repetidos podem ser feitas conjuntamente.

---

Uma pergunta relacionada pode ser vista em [Questão de matrizes](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/504306/quest%C3%A3o-de-matrizes/504464#504464) (um caso mais geral que o da questão atual e em C++).